# how add row to existing Datatable within dataset c#?

Tags: c#, datatable, dataset, .net-3.5

I am adding row/s to multiple `Datatable` then through my program I am adding these `Datatable` to `Dataset` what I am trying to do and I need to know now is

how to add row/s to one of these existing `Datatable` within existing `Dataset`?

Comment: Dataset have a property named Tables and Datatable have a property named TableName try access MyDataSet.Tables["TableName".Rows.Add(****);

Answer (score 0):

The class DataSet directly supports merging data in the form of DataRow or DataTable. Query for your DataSet object and perform whatever operations you require.

```
public void Merge(DataRow[] rows, bool preserveChanges, MissingSchemaAction missingSchemaAction);
public void Merge(DataRow[] rows);
public void Merge(DataTable table, bool preserveChanges, MissingSchemaAction missingSchemaAction);
public void Merge(DataSet dataSet, bool preserveChanges, MissingSchemaAction missingSchemaAction);
public void Merge(DataSet dataSet);
public void Merge(DataSet dataSet, bool preserveChanges);
```

Answer (score 0):

You could try something like this:

```
DataSet dataSet = new DataSet("DataSetName");
dataSet.Tables.Add("TableName");

var tableIndex = dataSet.Tables.IndexOf("TableName");
dataSet.Tables[tableIndex].Rows.Add(someDataRow);
```